# Can I declare a global function from namespaced code?

Tags: php, function, namespaces, global

I want to avoid creating another file just to escape the namespace.

Comment: Why don't you make all global functions in one file called: globals.php then include it inside all your php files?

Comment: Can you give an example or explain in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. For others interested see below.

```
namespace { function myFunction() { ... } }
```